# How to get coefficients and feature importances from MultiOutputRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to perform a MultiOutput Regression using ElasticNet and Random Forests as follows:

```python
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_features, y, test_size=0.30,random_state=0)
```

Elastic Net

```python
l1_range=np.arange(0.1,1.05,0.1).tolist()

regr_Enet=ElasticNetCV(cv=5,copy_X=True,n_alphas=100,l1_ratio=l1_range,selection='cyclic',normalize=False,verbose =2,n_jobs=1)

regr_multi_Enet= MultiOutputRegressor(regr_Enet)##ElasticNetCV

regr_multi_Enet.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Random Forest

```python
max_depth = 20
number_of_trees=100

regr_multi_RF=MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=number_of_trees,max_depth=max_depth,random_state=0,n_jobs=1,verbose=1))

regr_multi_RF.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_multirf = regr_multi_RF.predict(X_test)
```

Everything is going well, however I haven't found a way to obtain the coefficients (coef_ ) or most important features (feature_importances_) of the model. When I write:

```python
regr_multi_Enet.coef_
regr_multi_RF.feature_importances_
```

It shows the following error:

```python
AttributeError: 'MultiOutputRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
AttributeError: 'MultiOutputRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

I have read the documentation on MultiOutputRegressor but I cannot find a way to extract the coefficients. How to retrieve them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MultiOutputRegressor itself doesn't have these attributes - you need to access the underlying estimators first using the `estimators_` attribute (which, although not mentioned in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html), it exists indeed - see the docs for [MultiOutputClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html)). Here is a reproducible example:

```python
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

# dummy data
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
W = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]])

regr_multi_RF=MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor())
regr_multi_RF.fit(X,W)

# how many estimators?
len(regr_multi_RF.estimators_)
# 2

regr_multi_RF.estimators_[0].feature_importances_
# array([ 0.4,  0.6])

regr_multi_RF.estimators_[1].feature_importances_
# array([ 0.4,  0.4])

regr_Enet = ElasticNet()
regr_multi_Enet= MultiOutputRegressor(regr_Enet)
regr_multi_Enet.fit(X, W)

regr_multi_Enet.estimators_[0].coef_
# array([ 0.08333333,  0.        ])

regr_multi_Enet.estimators_[1].coef_
# array([ 0.08333333,  0.        ])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
regr_multi_Enet.estimators_[0].coef_
```

To get the coefficients of the first estimator etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! For the sake of completeness: in the case of random forest - regr_multi_RF.estimators_[0].feature_importances_

Comment: doesn't work for     knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=3, leaf_size=20)
    regr = MultiOutputRegressor(knn)

Answer (score 0):

```
    from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
        
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
        
    params = {'n_estimators': 500, 'max_depth':3, 'learning_rate': 0.1} 
        
    reg = MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(**params, random_state = 123))
    reg.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    
    ###  feature importance 
    reg.estimators_[0]           # for estimator 0
    reg.estimators_[0].feature_importances_
    print (feature_importance) 

    sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)
    pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + 0.5
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx], align="center")
    plt.yticks(pos, np.array(X.columns)[sorted_idx])
    plt.title("Feature Importance")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.