# TypeError: predict() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, mlp

I looked for this error on stackoverflow and found several posts, but no one adressing this specific situation.

I have the following dataframe:

[image: df]

the inputvariables and outputvariables are defined in this code:

```
xcol=["h","o","p","d","ddlt","devdlt","sl","lt"]
ycol=["Q","r"]
x=df[xcol].values
y=df[ycol].values
```

My goal is to guess the output values Q & r, based on the inputs (x). 
I have tried two ways and both are failing. With the first one, I tried a multi-ouput regressor.

I first split up the data in test and training data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
y_train = y_train.ravel()
y_test = y_test.ravel()
```

then import the function:

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
```

and then try to predict Q & r:

```
reg= MultiOutputRegressor(estimator=100, n_jobs=None)
reg=reg.predict(X_train, y_train)
```

And this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: predict() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Next thing I tried was a neural network. After assigning the columns x and y, I made the neural network:

```
# neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:

#Step 1: 
def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
    #set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
    self.inodes = inputnodes
    self.hnodes = hiddennodes
    self.onodes = outputnodes

    #link weight matrices, wih and who (weights in hidden en output layers), 
    # we are going to create matrices for the multiplication of it to get an 
    # output
    # weights inside the arrays (matrices) are w_i_j, where link is from node 
    # i to node j in the next layer
    #w11 w21
    #w12 w22 etc
    self.wih = numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.inodes,-0.5),( self.hnodes, 
    self.inodes))
    self.who = numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnodes,-0.5),( self.onodes, 
    self.hnodes))

    # setting the learning rate
    self.lr = learningrate

    # activation function is the sigmoid function
    self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)

    pass

    #Step 2:
def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
    #convert input lists to 2d array (matrice)
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
    targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

    #calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    #calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
    # output layer error is the (target-actual)
    output_errors = targets -final_outputs
    #hidden layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined 
    at hidden nodes
    hidden_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

    #update the weights for the links between the hidden and output layers
    self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors*final_outputs * (1.0- 
    final_outputs)),numpy.transpose(hidden_outputs))

    # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
    self.wih += self.lr*numpy.dot((hidden_errors*hidden_outputs*(1.0- 
    hidden_outputs)),numpy.transpose(inputs))

    pass

    #Step 3
def query(self, inputs_list):
    #convert input lists to 2d array (matrice)
    inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

    #calculate signals into hidden layer
    hidden_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from hidden layer
    hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

    #calculate signals into final output layer
    final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
    #calculate signals emerging from final output layer
    final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

    return final_outputs
```

I then created an instance of a neural network:

```
   #Creating instance of neural network 

   #number of input, hidden and output nodes
   input_nodes = 8
   hidden_nodes = 100
   output_nodes = 2

   #learning rate is 0.8
   learning_rate = 0.8

   #create instance of neural network
   n = neuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)
```

I got 8 inputs and 2 outputs that need to be predicted.

I then trained the neural network:

```
# train the neural network
# go through all records in the training data set 
for record in df:
    #scale and shift te inputs
    inputs = x
    #create the target output values 
    targets = y
    n.train(inputs, targets)
    pass
```

and then I want to query the guessed outputs and now it goes wrong:

so i want to make 2 extra columns in the dataframe with the guesses of Q (Q*) & r (r*):

```
df["Q*","r*"] = n.query(x)
```

I really don't know how to do this properly. This above code gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Any help appreciated.

Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first part (`MultiOutputRegressor`) of your question, there are several issues with your code...

To start with, the `estimator` argument of `MultiOutputRegressor` should not be a number, but, as the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html#sklearn-multioutput-multioutputregressor) say:

> **estimator : *estimator object***
>
> An estimator object implementing fit and predict.

So, for [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_random_forest_regression_multioutput.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-random-forest-regression-multioutput-py), to use a random forest with default parameters, you should use

```
reg = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor())
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648383/how-to-get-coefficients-and-feature-importances-from-multioutputregressor/52649434#52649434) for some more examples)

Second, in your code you never *fit* your regressor; you should add

```
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

after the definition.

Third, `predict` doesn't take the ground truth values (`y_train` here) as arguments, only the features (`X_train`); from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.predict) again:

> **predict**(X)
>
> Predict multi-output variable using a model
>       trained for each target variable.
>
> **Parameters: X : *(sparse) array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)***
>
> Data.
>
> **Returns:    y : *(sparse) array-like, shape (n_samples, n_outputs)***
>
> Multi-output targets predicted across multiple predictors. Note: Separate models are generated for each predictor.

Since you also pass `y_train` in your code, you receive an expected error of one argument too many; simply change it to `reg.predict(X_train)`, and you will be fine.

Comment: thanks! However, there seems to be something other missing in my code. When I try to fit it, it gives me the error:                                                                                  ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7999, 15998]. And when i look at my X_train.shape, then this gives [7999,8] and my y_train.shape gives [15998,]. Any idea on this?

Comment: @StevenPauly Check the examples I have linked to see in what *form* exactly your inputs should be; maybe you should remove the `ravel` part (I don't have your data to try it myself)...

Comment: that was it exactly! thanks! The last thing is: how can I add the predicted values of the two outputs (Q and r) in 2 seperate columns in the dataframe?

Comment: @StevenPauly several ways here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas

Comment: I see. But adding a column is okay, but i'm stuck with the fact that I have 2 outputs. So if I have reg.predict(x) then my output will be 2 values. But how can I put them seperately in two columns?

Comment: @StevenPauly Break the operation in more lines - e.g. if your `query` function returns 2 values, do `pred=n.query(x)`, and then `df['Q_pred']=pred[0], df['r_pred']=pred[1]` or something like that (and you *certainly don't want* to have asterisks in column names!)

Comment: Good tip on the asterisks. I have now used: df['Q_pred']=reg.predict[0], df['r_pred']=reg.predict[1] (i'm using the first method, not the NN). But then he says: method not subscriptable and when I change the [] to (), then he gives the error: can't assign to function call.

Comment: @StevenPauly don't use `reg.predict[0]` - it's certainly invalid!!! As I said, *break* the predict operation in multiple lines - assign the prediction results to a variable first, and then see what you get as a result and how you will be able to put them into your df. Don't try to cut corners, go one step at a time!! If you keep on getting errors, please open a new question...